# add title bar in fancybox dialog

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have dialog generated using the fancybox.
I want to add titlebar to the title, below is my code sample.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#opener").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: does the element with `id="opener"` have a `title` attribute?

Comment: No, I dont how to add it.

Comment: sorry id has the titlei want to add it in dialog..

Comment: please edit your question and add your html code too

Comment: This might help: `http://fancybox.net/blog`  See the first blog entry (#7)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a title by specifying the object property 'title':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#opener").fancybox({ title: 'FancyBox Test' });
});
```